# Atom autocomplete ternjs not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, autocomplete, atom-editor, ternjs

I have the folowing project structure.

[image: project structure]

.tern-project content

```
{
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "libs": [
    "browser",
    "jquery"
  ],
  "loadEagerly": [
    "/bower-components/d3/d3.js"
  ]
}
```

I was tried to change d3.js to d3.min.js, completely remove the loadEagerly point from ternjs config. But nothing was helped.

.gitignore content

```
/bower_components
.tern-project
```

So. In logic.js I'm trying to write d3 but there is no such line in suggestions list. What am I doing wrong? Can't figure out why. No d3 and no d3's methods are in suggestions. No errors comes. Autocomplete works only for in project files, but nor for this bower_components. All needed Atom packages were installed (autocomplete-plus, ternjs)

[image]

Here I'm trying to write d3. (no suggestions), and then call enter method (no suggestions).

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I found the reason. All beacuase off this checkbox.

[image]

But there is another question then. How to use this checkbox (this is too convenient for me to refuse this option) and allow packages, like ternjs work correctly?

**Update**

Okay. Found different options for this. I can hide VCS ignored files from tree view and not exclude them from project. I think that all I need for now.